# tips in optimizing fast repeating calls (Objective-C, iPhone)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, optimization, nstimer

I build an app that has to do a certain task with very high accuracy over time(accepted error it's +/- 0.001s). I know that this depends very much on the actual tasks, however I can't make it precise enough even for the most basic task. I use a while loop on a separate thread(using NSOperation), as described in the code below. The problem I have it's that although the task repeats itself at low pace, the error it's very big for consecutive steps, 0.02s or 0.01  (see second section).

```
while (!self.isCancelled) {         
    NSLog(@"run");
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.5];
}
```

And the output is:

```
2011-03-26 12:17:03.836 Test[388:c6c7] run
2011-03-26 12:17:04.344 Test[388:c6c7] run
2011-03-26 12:17:04.852 Test[388:c6c7] run
2011-03-26 12:17:05.373 Test[388:c6c7] run
2011-03-26 12:17:05.880 Test[388:c6c7] run
2011-03-26 12:17:06.381 Test[388:c6c7] run
2011-03-26 12:17:06.904 Test[388:c6c7] run
```

See how the error varies form 0.01s to 0.02s. For example time between 6.381 and 6.904 it's
0.523.

It's this because of the debug printing time overhead? Is there a way to test it better? Can this somehow be improved? I'm pretty sure I'm not doing something right, the error it's to big for such a pace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want it to repeat at an interval, you can use this:

[scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval%3ainvocation%3arepeats%3a)

I think the issue with your code might be that it is executing, **then** getting timed to go off after 0.5 seconds, so the actual time interval is `executionTimeForFunction + 0.5`.

On that note, I seem to remember `NSLog` is actually pretty slow.

Comment: Hey Chris! Thanks for the answer, seems to makes sense. Will give it a try. Thanks again!

Comment: Ok, that was the problem indeed! I didn't use a timer as suggested however I took the date BEFORE the code execution and then used sleepUntilDate instead of sleepForTimeInterval. Finally I got an error of less than 0.001 even for other more complex tasks, not just a simple log. Great, thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a realtime OS. 1ms isn't realistic.

Comment: OK, but still, I get an error of 2 centiseconds. And I run it on simulator. I still think the code it's wrong...

Comment: As Chris said, you are sleeping to at least 500ms. A timer might improve your accuracy, but you need to take into account the actual time between timer ticks, and base your calculations on this. If system is stressed, low on memory, etc. your ticks will be off.

Comment: And you're logging. NSLogs will introduce a fair amount of overhead.